# Sending emails from outbox when outlook is closed

Tags: vba, email, batch-file, outlook

My application uses a third party tool which sends reports via email using outlook.
This functionality was working correctly with outlook express and windows 2003 server. Now we have upgraded to windows 2008 R2 and Outlook 2010 it needs outlook to be open to send out emails or else the emails just sit in the outbox.
We don't have any control over third party tool and application is in maintenance mode so no code changes can be done. And we cannot keep outlook open.
Is there any way emails can be sent from outbox without the outlook being open?
Like any script which can be run outside of the application?
Or is there any setting in outlook?

Comment: Would opening Outlook, sending the Mail and immediately closing it again be an option?

Comment: if you know your smpt credentials you can check [blat](http://www.blat.net/?faq/index.html)

Comment: No opening outlook is not an option.

Comment: VBA (and probably VBScript) can manipulate Outlook without Outlook being open.

Comment: blat is not an option as the third party tool only uses outlook. I need something which will send emails which are in outbox when outlook is closed.

Comment: Would CDO be an option? [Example 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286431) | [Example 2](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm) | [lmgtfy](https://www.google.com/search?q=cdo%20html%20email)

Comment: No. I need is some script which can send emails from outbox when outlook is closed as the third party component just puts the emails in the outbox.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for is possible, could be wrong though. Outlook has to be opened (albeit programmatically) to send an email. Outlook has always opened up to send an email when using the Outlook Object. You can probably program something in to quit outlook after all emails are sent, so it's not left open longer than needed. Or as others have mentioned, rework your solution to send the emails directly through the email server (e.g. CDO/blat).

Comment: As its a third party tool I cannot change the way it works. I am trying to see if I can write any VB script so that I can do send/receive on outlook without opening it. I am not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

After all the research I found out that outlook 2010 cannot send emails which are in the outbox when it is closed. Even the VB Script I wrote opens it in the background. Thank you to everyone who tried to help. We are using thunderbird now. It does not solve the issue which I asked but it is free so we can create multiple from accounts which we need and keep it open.